# What does GHKWXUE mean in English?

Tags: meaning, usage

What does GHKWXUE mean in English?

It's the brand name if a pot/pressure cooker I'm looking into buy and I wondered what it means.

Comment: [This](https://shroomco.io/products/ghkwxue-25l-pressure-cooker-with-pressure-gauge) seems to be the pressure cooker, but I couldn't find anything in Chinese about GHKWXUE.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't related to Chinese at all, but I guess I'll answer this.

It's not a real word. Amazon has lots of these brands with just random letters as names. There's actually information about this online, it turns out that these random letter names are because Amazon required third-party sellers to register their name as a trademark. So, the Amazon sellers just came up with random letters combinations so that their trademark would almost definitely be approved as unique. (source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Bq-6GeRhys)

And yes, it turns out that GHKWXUE is indeed a registered trademark with the USPTO owned by some random dude in China named Zhang Yongfeng. (by the way, GHKWXUE sells pressure cookers as well as wine buckets) And, of course, the trademark filings list exactly zero foreign meanings for this name. It's pretty easy to find a lot of other random letter trademarks like this one too that also sell similarly improbable combinations of products, like QDYZPP, which sells lawnmowers, beer pumps, tobacco processing machines, and engraving machines, though I couldn't find any other trademarks owned by this exact Zhang Yongfeng.

(By the way, if you're interested in seeing the actual trademark filings, you can search it up [here](http://tess2.uspto.gov/). I can't share any links because they expire after only a few minutes)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a real word.

Amazon has a lot of Chinese brands that use seemingly-random combinations of letters as their name.

I can't offer any proof, but I suspect many of those random-name-brands are likely manufactured by the same manufacturer. I'm surprised I haven't seen anyone on the internet talk about this yet.

Comment: Several searches directs my attention to a brand named 共好 whose cooking appliances seem to use "GHKW" as part of their model numbers.

Comment: @magni GHKWXUE is a brand name, not a model name.